# Can I buy IBM DeepBlue?

Tags: engines, history

The IBM DeepBlue which is a chess computer that won against the one of the world's top chess players Kasparov was an IBM research project. Would it be possible for me to buy it?

Comment: With [todays computers (2012/2013)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS#Hardware_costs), you can reach about 2-16 TFLOPS at a reasonable cost (USD 400-3000). This is about 200 to more than 1000 times the power [Deep Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_%28chess_computer%29#Deep_Blue_versus_Kasparov) had. Probably, you can build a similar chess computer with a contemporary off the shelf chess program.

Comment: I have no idea why this question ended up in my hot list, but it's worth noting that the iPhone 6 (released in 2015) was capable of over 20GFLOPS, almost twice the power of Deep Blue in 1997. Also, modern chess AI like stockfish are much smarter than Deep Blue's brute force algorithm, making much better utilization of available computing power. I would guess that stockfish running on a $35 Raspberry Pi 4 could easily beat Deep Blue 100 times out of 100. At the other extreme, the RTX 3080 ($800 MSRP) is capable of 119 TFLOPS.

Comment: @MooseBoys I read the question as not about needing the raw computational capabilities of DeepBlue but having the engine for historical interest and to see how it act and perform today.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you have to ask IBM, but it's probably not for sale. Right now the custom made computer is on display at the [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/chess/full_record.php?iid=art-43305f13ef377).

Answer (score 4):

Most (all?) modern chess computers are software programs which can be run from anyone's computer. Back in the bad old days of 1999, though, IBM couldn't get what they wanted from some random laptop. They made Deep Blue using custom hardware which made mass production economically impossible. So no, you cannot buy it because they were never made for sale.

Answer (score 2):

Deep Blue is a computing machine designed by the IBM research group, and is very customized.  There is only one, and there is no intention to recreate it.

The machine itself is so tied with IBM's legacy and triumphs, even today, that it would be unthinkable for them, at this time, to part with it for any reason.

Further, it is not in a playable state, and requires significant effort to set up and run. It is unlikely that they would find a reason or need to bring it back up to a playable state, because as long as it remains unpowered it can't be beat. Similar to retiring after a major win, there is nothing to gain and everything to lose by coming out of retirement.

The 15 year anniversary was celebrated by IBM with the creation of a tumbler:

http://ibmdeepblue15.tumblr.com/

So even now they still use it as part of their marketing and outreach efforts. Read the articles and watch the videos there and you may get a glimpse of the effort require not only to create the machine, but to run it.

If you believe you have the resources or wherewithal to convince them to part with it or make it playable, you had best discuss the topic with them directly - this site is not a Deep Blue support board:

http://www.research.ibm.com/

Comment: It's funny to me that a behemoth company like IBM would do PR on one of its most famous accomplishments on  relatively underground Tumblr

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, it was sold off to two different museums.

See

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)

> Today, one of the two racks that made up Deep Blue is held by the National Museum of American History, having previously been displayed in an exhibit about the Information Age,[14] while the other rack was acquired by the Computer History Museum in 1997, and is displayed in the Revolution exhibit's "Artificial Intelligence and Robotics" gallery