# The exsistence of IBM’s Deep Blue

Tags: theory, history, computer-chess

How would IBM’s Deep Blue fair against modern day champions like Carlsen? Was it decommissioned after Kasparov's game?

Comment: See also http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5702/can-i-buy-ibm-deepblue

Answer (score 2):

The match with Kasparov was very close - 3.5 - 2.5 and it is arguable that Kasparov's loss was due to psychological factors. Until Carlsen's recent disastrous tournament where he went to pieces psychologically after over stepping the time control in round one I would have said that Carlsen is psychologically stronger than Kasparov but now I'm not so sure.

Modern day players like Carlsen have closed the gap that existed between Kasparov and the rest without opening up a big gap. I want to say that Carlsen would beat Deep Blue but I suspect the truth is that it would be a close match again.

Deep Blue was dismantled and parts of it can now be seen in two different US museums - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer).

Answer (score 0):

New generation always break the records of previous generation, It happens in every game, for example if I talk about soccer New generation has better training and strong emphasis on psychology factor. In addition Garry Kasparov doesn't have that kind of concentration  Carlson have , as he has to take care Russian Politics and his Professional Chess academy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Chess_Association. 3rd factor I think is age with age function of brain deteriorate at-least I have learn it from my brain. These factor may have played have some role. But I don't want to take away brilliance of Magnus Carlson. He is simply awesome and can beat even faster computers than Deep Blue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to let chess players improve (substituting Carlsen of today for Kasparov of two decades ago) before this theoretical match, you'll have to let the computer's hardware and software improve, as well. Given the overall rate of improvement in top Grandmaster skill vs that of computer hardware and software over the last twenty years (hardware improvements alone would allow DB a calculation speed gain of roughly 1000 times, for example -- remember in 1996 the typical desktop CPU was a single-core 75Mhz Pentium) I suspect a modern version of Deep Blue could probably give Carlsen pawn odds and still not lose a game.

Answer (score -3):

It will fail miserably against Carlsen since it was designed specially for playing against Kasparov.

It was decommissioned since it was a single purpose machine and had achieved the designated goal.

The hardware was sold to a Sheikh in Middle East.